# Is there any way to stop tracking from git one specific type of files?

Tags: git, github

By mistake I have pushed everything to git and now I want to stop tracking all `html` files. I know for a single file we can use

`git rm --cached <file-name>` or `git rm -r --cached <folder-name>`

But in my case the number of the files are too high. Is there git command which removes a specific type of files from tracking?

Answer (score 1):

```
find ./your-git-work-dir -name '*.html' -exec git rm {} \;
```

See the find manual page - https://linux.die.net/man/1/find

Comment: It worked but not sure why this command actually put everything in that folder in gitignore. I wanted only for html.

Comment: @EMT you asked to remove tracking, not to add to .gitignore.